# Ошибка при подключении session

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить такую ошибку:

> `User runet_9933402 already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections`

Comment: дай больше информации, код и т.д

ошибка говорит о том что пользователь runet_9933402 уже подключен больше, чем это доступно в 'max_user_connections'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень похожая ситуация рассмотрена [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079531/mysqli-error-user-already-has-more-than-max-user-connections-active-connectio), ну а если по-русски, то у тебя кончились коннекшены к MySql, решение: увеличить кол-во `max_connections` / `max_user_connections` в `my.conf`

Comment: Спасибо больше=)